# Regarding subplot and sub-sub plot location in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having some trouble understanding the subplot concept. As I understand subplots are organized (number of rows, numbers of column, and the plot number or how many places the plot is taking)

I have this code:

```
from pandas import util
import pandas.util.testing as testing
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl

df = util.testing.makeDataFrame()


with mpl.rc_context(rc={'font.family': 'serif', 'font.weight': 'light', 'font.size': 12}):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize= (12, 6))

    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, (1,2))
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    df['A'].plot(ax=ax, color = 'g')
    df['B'].plot(ax=ax2, color ='g')

    fig.add_subplot(223)
    df['C'].plot(color='r')
    plt.axvline(x = 7, color = 'b', label = 'axvline - full height')
    
    fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
    df = df.round(0)
    ax3 = df['D'].plot(kind='bar')
    ax3.legend( prop={'size': 6})

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Which produces this plot:
[image]
(1,2) in `ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, (1,2))` does not say location or plot number, isn't it confusing? This is because `ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, (3,2))` would mean there are 3 plots and taking 2 places but it throws this error

> IndexError: GridSpec slice would result in no space allocated for
> subplot

Why the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation of the tuple (third parameter) is incorrect: `ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, (3,2))` says 4 subplots (2 rows x 2 columns) with the following indices:

```
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

and `(3, 2)` would be a subplot that spans from index # 3 to # 2 which is impossible as they are on a diagonal. `(1, 3)` would be a subplot on the left over the full hight, `(3, 4)` at the bottom over the full width etc.

From the docs of [`subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot):

> Three integers (nrows, ncols, index). The subplot will take the index
> position on a grid with nrows rows and ncols columns. index starts at
> 1 in the upper left corner and increases to the right. index can also
> be a two-tuple specifying the (first, last) indices (1-based, and
> including last) of the subplot, e.g., fig.add_subplot(3, 1, (1, 2))
> makes a subplot that spans the upper 2/3 of the figure.